# How to reshape a tensor based on first index using tensorflow when finding a workaround tf.unique axis=1

Tags: python, tensorflow, unique

I want help in converting a tensor to a new format based on values at its 1st index. Normally I would do this using a loop in python, but I would like to learn how to do this in Tensorflow. In following code `x[0,0]` & `x[1,0]` are `0` so they are grouped in 0th index of the output

```
  x=tf.constant([[0, 1],[0, 2],[1, 1],[2, 10],[2, 2]])
  #output=[[1,2],[1],[10,2]] #i would like the output in this format
```

I am doing so when trying to pick unique values from a 2D Tensor.

```
y=tf.constant([[1,2],[2,3],[1,2]] #output should be [[1,2],[2,3]]
```

Comment: What does the title of the question mean actually ? You have a workaround ?

Comment: I did not have a work around for tf.unique (2D_tensor)  when I posted this question. But now I do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487990/find-unique-values-in-a-2d-tensor-using-tensorflow/51487991#51487991