# Find Unique values in a 2D Tensor using Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

tf.unique currently only works on 1D tensors. How can I find unique values in a 2D tensor.

```
ip=tf.constant([[1,2,1],[3,4,1],[5,6,1],[1,2,1]])
#op should be  = [[1,2,1],[3,4,1],[5,6,1]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following function takes 2D tensor as IP and will return Unique 2D Tensor

```
def tf_unique_2d(self, x):
    x_shape = tf.shape(x)  # (3,2)
    x1 = tf.tile(x, [1, x_shape[0]])  # [[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[3,4],[3,4],[3,4]..]
    x2 = tf.tile(x, [x_shape[0], 1])  # [[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[3,4],[3,4],[3,4]..]

    x1_2 = tf.reshape(x1, [x_shape[0] * x_shape[0], x_shape[1]])
    x2_2 = tf.reshape(x2, [x_shape[0] * x_shape[0], x_shape[1]])
    cond = tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(x1_2, x2_2), axis=1)
    cond = tf.reshape(cond, [x_shape[0], x_shape[0]])  # reshaping cond to match x1_2 & x2_2
    cond_shape = tf.shape(cond)
    cond_cast = tf.cast(cond, tf.int32)  # convertin condition boolean to int
    cond_zeros = tf.zeros(cond_shape, tf.int32)  # replicating condition tensor into all 0's

    # CREATING RANGE TENSOR
    r = tf.range(x_shape[0])
    r = tf.add(tf.tile(r, [x_shape[0]]), 1)
    r = tf.reshape(r, [x_shape[0], x_shape[0]])

    # converting TRUE=1 FALSE=MAX(index)+1 (which is invalid by default) so when we take min it wont get selected & in end we will only take values <max(indx).
    f1 = tf.multiply(tf.ones(cond_shape, tf.int32), x_shape[0] + 1)
    f2 = tf.ones(cond_shape, tf.int32)
    cond_cast2 = tf.where(tf.equal(cond_cast, cond_zeros), f1, f2)  # if false make it max_index+1 else keep it 1

    # multiply range with new int boolean mask
    r_cond_mul = tf.multiply(r, cond_cast2)
    r_cond_mul2 = tf.reduce_min(r_cond_mul, axis=1)
    r_cond_mul3, unique_idx = tf.unique(r_cond_mul2)
    r_cond_mul4 = tf.subtract(r_cond_mul3, 1)

    # get actual values from unique indexes
    op = tf.gather(x, r_cond_mul4)

    return (op)
```

Comment: to others who are looking for higher dimensional search, you can reshape your tensor to 2D and search, then reshape back the ones that are unique.

Comment: @Anton well, it kinda defeat the purpose of reshaping 3d matrix isn't it? By reshaping I loose the information of first dimension - batch. And you can't reshape the result with original tensor since the results are now reduced!

Answer (score 4):

**Answer in April 2022**

Since version 2.2, Tensorflow has supported find unique 1-D tensor in a 2D tensor using `tf.raw_ops.UniqueV2`.

```py
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> a = tf.constant([[1, 2, 1], [3, 4, 1], [5, 6, 1], [1, 2, 1]])
>>> y, idx = tf.raw_ops.UniqueV2(x=a, axis=[0])
>>> y
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 2, 1],
       [3, 4, 1],
       [5, 6, 1]], dtype=int32)>
>>> idx
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 1, 2, 0], dtype=int32)>
```

Check the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/raw_ops/UniqueV2) for more details.

Comment: This is the best answer imo - thanks @JonnyJack

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to first reshape your tensor to be a 1D tensor, then use `tf.unique` (which currently only accepts 1D tensors, not sure why!) or `tf.unique_with_counts` (depending on whether you also need the counts of the unique elements), and then, if you also need the indices of the unique values to have the same shape as the original tensor, you can reshape also the indices. The following **TensorFlow 2.1** program illustrates this.

```
import tensorflow as tf # TF 2.1


def get_uniques(t):
    t1d = tf.reshape(t, shape=(-1,))
    # or tf.unique, if you don't need counts
    uniques, idx, counts = tf.unique_with_counts(t1d) 
    return uniques, tf.reshape(idx, shape=tf.shape(t)), counts


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_tensor = tf.constant([[1, 2, 1], [3, 4, 1], [5, 6, 1], [1, 2, 1]])

    uniques, idx, counts = get_uniques(my_tensor)

    tf.print("tf.shape(uniques) =", tf.shape(uniques))
    tf.print("tf.shape(idx) =", tf.shape(idx))
    tf.print("tf.shape(counts) =", tf.shape(counts))
    tf.print("uniques =", uniques)
```

Comment: The objective in the question was to find unique 1D tensors in a 2D tensor. This answer finds unique scalars in a 2D tensor.

Comment: @prouast The question was "How can I find **unique values** in a 2D tensor." and not "How can I find unique sub-tensors or arrays in a 2D tensor". There's no specification that the unique values must be sub-arrays. The part `#op should be  = [[1,2,1],[3,4,1],[5,6,1]]` also doesn't clarify anything. It's not my problem if the OP did not ask a clear enough question and if you're looking for an answer that is not my answer.